# Is there a way for extconf.rb to not use certain warning flags?

Tags: c, ruby

I just updated gcc from the default 4.2.1 to 4.5.  But when I run ruby extconf.rb, I get a warning flag created that gcc doesn't recognize.

```
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wshorten-64-to-32"
```

Is there a way to edit the extconf.rb file to tell it not to use this warning flag, or is there a way to get gcc to recognize it?  Here is my gcc version if it is helpful:

```
 $  gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin10/4.5.3/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin10
Configured with: ../gcc-4.5.3/configure --prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,java --libdir=/opt/local/lib/gcc45 --includedir=/opt/local/include/gcc45 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-4.5 --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-4.5 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/gcc45/c++/ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --enable-stage1-checking --disable-multilib --enable-fully-dynamic-string
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.5.3 (GCC)
```

Answer (score 1):

mkmf generates makefile configurations by using a table of strings defined in `CONFIG`, and the warning flags are in `CONFIG['warnflags']`, so you can do something like

```
CONFIG['warnflags'].slice!(/ -Wshorten-64-to-32/)
```

before `create_makefile` is called to get rid of a specific warning flag.